# How to delete all versions of a file in svn using svnkit

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

i need to delete all the versions/histroy of a file in svn. I know how to delete a file in svn  using following code

```
            ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager((String) userKey,
                    (String) pwd);
            repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
            ourClientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(null,
                    repository.getAuthenticationManager());
            updateClient = ourClientManager.getUpdateClient();
            System.out.println("SVN Authendication updateClient status - " + updateClient);
            System.out.println("Start to delete an existing directory at '" + url + "'...");
            try {
                long deletedRevision = ourClientManager.getCommitClient().doDelete(new SVNURL[]{importToURL},
                        "New directory deletion").getNewRevision();
            } catch (SVNException svne) {
                System.err.println("Error on delete directory from SVN" + svne);
            }
```

With this code am able to delete the file but there is no change in svn size. For this i need to delete its versions/history also to reduce size.Any other idea using java

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this from any Subversion client because Subversion revisions are, for all intents and purposes, immutable.

To complete remove all traces of an item from a Subversion repository, you need administrative access to the repository and must complete dump, filter & reload the repository (or perform a sync which filters out the item(s), then switch the original and the new copy).

See [the Subversion FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal).